# Protecting iframe from other domains

Tags: .htaccess, iframe, embed, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I created a video embed page in 000webhost website which then will get embedded into my other website running on Blogger. I don't want anyone to access the 000webhost video page directly or to embed on other websites except my blogger website. I know it's possible with the help of Content Security Policy, x-frame-options, .htaccess.
But all of them have limitations like some won't work in chrome and Firefox, some need server side configurations etc...

This is the Content Security Policy for example-

```
X-Frame-Options: Allow-From http://example.com
```

so is there a break through in this situation?

tried using .htaccess

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from mysite.com
```

Content Security Policy  too

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' http://example.com
```

Edit: tried a JavaScript code but not working as expected. When directly accessed to the 000webhost video page it will redirect to blogger page but when in frame it's not redirecting

```
    <script>
if (top.location.host != "https://example.com") {
    window.location.href='https://example.com/bloggerdomain';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The ALLOW-FROM option in X-Frame-Options had limited support, and now that IE is gone there is pretty much no support for it anymore.

Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors should work if you put it in a response header with .htaccess. It will not work in a meta tag.